# List members of a character class

Tags: php, regex

I am creating a function that I would like to generate random strings from a given set of characters. I would like to allow users to specify a regex character class instead of requiring them to specify every single character.
For example:

```
function a($length, $allowed_chars){
    for ($i = 0, $salt = ""; $i < $length; $i++){
        $salt .= __GET_ONE_RANDOM_CHAR_FROM_ALLOWED_CHARS__;
    }
}
```

If allowed chars is a string of all allowed characters, then this is simple:

```
$characterList{mt_rand(0,strlen($characterList)-1)};
```

I would like to be able to specify allowed chars like this `"./0-9A-Za-z"` instead of `"./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didint check but, i think you will understand main idea

```
function a($length, $allowed_chars){

    $allowedCharsList = join('', array_merge(range(chr(0x1f), chr(0x23)), range(chr(0x25), chr(0x80)) )); //all printable (ascii) characters except '$'
    $allowed_chars = preg_replace("/[^$allowed_chars]/", '', $allowedCharsList);
    for ($i = 0, $salt = ""; $i < $length; $i++){
        $salt .= $allowed_chars{mt_rand(0,strlen($allowed_chars)-1)};
    }

    return $salt;
}


echo a(10, '0-9h-w');
```

Comment: this does exactly the opposite. It deletes all in `$userList` from `$allowedCharsList`.

Comment: That requires me to have a list of every possible character (including all printable characters for my encoding) to begin with. I would like to avoid that too.

Comment: I changed it to `join('', array_merge(range(chr(0x1f), chr(0x23)), range(chr(0x25), chr(0x80)) ));` because '$' is not valid in these salts (since it is the delimiter)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
// build a string with all printable char
$str = join('', range(' ','~'));
// define allowed char
$allowedChar = './a-zA-Z0-9';
// replace all non-allowed char by nothing, preg_quote escapes regex char
$str = preg_replace("~[^".preg_quote($allowedChar)."]~", "", $str);
echo $str,"\n";
```

**output:**

```
./0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```